# Why nhibernate doesn't allow to make batch insert during stateless session with identity identifier?

Tags: c#, sql-server, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I'm trying to optimize database calls from my code using batching in NHibernate. I'm working on a process that sends more than 1 thousand queries separately (I want to optimize this).

The NHibernate version is 4.

The core problem that I'm using Identity type for generation ID.

I tried to use both sessions and stateless sessions.

I would like to use batch insert even for identity column mapping. In case I work with a stateless session, which does not collect cache on my insertions, I don't understand why I do not allow me to batch my queries.

Is that is possible?

P.S. I don't want to use SQLBulkCopy. My options are limited to Nhiberante features.

Comment: *"I'm working on process with sends more than 1 thousand of queries separately."* this sounds like your *real* problem

Comment: @Larnu sorry, I wrote it wrong. Fixed description. I mean that currently my process sending 1000+ separate queries, but I want to batch them to improve performance.

Comment: How long does the queries take to run? I do not suspect batching them will improve performance.  The SQL Server is multi-process and already is optimized to use all the cores of the microprocessor and runs queries in parallel.  The database also locks transactions so there are no conflicts when more than one user simultaneously accesses the database.  As long as you run your queries asynchronously in c# the queries should already be optimized.

Comment: It is 100-200 ms on average, but there are a lot of them, which cause performance issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is that is possible?

Batching is not supported by NHibernate if key column is identity. This is because, NHibernate have to execute the INSERT statement and get back the generated (by RDBMS) identity. This will not be possible in case of batching.

> Note that NHibernate disables insert batching at the ADO level transparently if you use an identity identifier generator.
>   <sub>[Source](https://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/batch.html)</sub>

> I don't want to use SQLBulkCopy. My options are limited to Nhiberante features.

SQL Bulk Copy is commonly used alternative for this scenario bypassing NHibernate; consider it.